# Get frequency counts for a subset of elements in a column

Tags: count, stata, frequency

I may be missing some elegant ways in Stata to get to this example, which has to do with electrical parts and observed monthly failures etc.

```
clear
input   str3 (PartID  Type   FailType) 
ABD A 4
BBB S 0
ABD A 3
ABD A 4
ABC A 2
BBB A 0
ABD B 1
ABC B 7
BBB C 1
BBB D 0

end
```

I would like to group by (`bysort`) each `PartID` and record the highest frequency for `FailType` within each `PartID` type.  Ties can be broken arbitrarily, and preferably, the lower one can be picked.

I looked at `groups` etc., but do not know how to peel off certain elements from the result set.  So that is a major question for me.  If you execute a query, how do you select only the elements you want for the next computation?  Something like n(0) is the count, n(1) is the mean etc.  I was able to use `contract`, `bysort` etc. and create a separate data set which I then `merge`d back into the main set with an extra column  There must be something simple using `gen` or `egen` so that there is no need to create an extra data set.

```
The expected results here will be:
PartID Freq 
ABD 4 #(4 occurs twice)
ABC 2  #(tie broken with minimum)
BBB 0  #(0 occurs 3 times)
```

Please let me know how I can pick off specific elements that I need from a result set (can be from duplicate reports, `tab` etc.)

Part II - Clarification: Perhaps I should have clarified and split the question into two parts. For example, if I issue this followup command after running your code: `tabdisp Type, c(Freq)`. It may print out a nice table. Can I then use that (derived) table to perform more computations programatically?

For example get the first row of the table.

```
Table. ---------------------- 
Type| Freq ----------+----------- 
A | -1 
B | -1 
C | -1 
D | -3 
S | -3 
---------------------- –
```

Comment: I trimmed this question to focus on precise code rather than discursive or personal commentary and to remove references to R: you show no R code and are not asking a precise R question. This still is hard to follow (e.g. what have means got to do with your problem). Note that variable is the Stata term for what you here call column.

Comment: On your Part II, I can make little sense of your example, as (1) `Freq` is defined in terms of `PartID FailType` so why tabulate it in terms of `Type`? (2) `Freq` is not negative at the end of my code, so you are doing something different but not showing us your code. As a general question, `tabdisp` is the end of a sequence for showing results already calculated; it has no extra value for later calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this difficult to follow (see comment on question), but some technique is demonstrated here. The numbers of observations in subsets of observations defined by `by:` are given by `_N`. The rest is sorting tricks. Negating the frequency is a way to select the highest frequency and the lowest `Type` which I think is what you are after when splitting ties. Negating back gets you the positive frequencies.

```
clear
input   str3 (PartID  Type   FailType) 
    ABD A 4
    BBB S 0
    ABD A 3
    ABD A 4
    ABC A 2
    BBB A 0
    ABD B 1
    ABC B 7
    BBB C 1
    BBB D 0
end 

bysort PartID FailType: gen Freq = -_N 
bysort PartID (Freq Type) : gen ToShow = _n == 1
replace Freq = -Freq 
list PartID Type FailType Freq  if ToShow  

     +---------------------------------+
     | PartID   Type   FailType   Freq |
     |---------------------------------|
  1. |    ABC      A          2      1 |
  3. |    ABD      A          4      2 |
  7. |    BBB      A          0      3 |
     +---------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have reformatted my initial question to make it more specific.  _Mean_ is not required for the example itself.  I was asking how I can programatically assign a statistic such as a mean or a frequency to a variable that I can then use elsewhere,

Comment: See comment on your revised question. My answer already exemplifies putting results into new variables. There are many other methods and they can't be explained briefly.